# Asp.net Set Textbox 1 to Equal Textbox 2

Tags: asp.net, javascript

What's the **cleanest** way, like **1 line** of JavaScript code, to set one text box's text property to equal another?

e.g. the JavaScript way to accomplish this:

```
txtShipCity.Text = txtCity.Text;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('txtShipCity').value = document.getElementById('txtCity').value;
```

Sweeten it with jQuery:

```
$('#txtShipCity').val($('#txtCity').val());
```

Although you will probably have to use the `ClientID`s of the two textboxes, so your JS might end up looking pretty nasty, like:

```
document.getElementById('<%= txtShipCity.ClientID %>').value = document.getElementById('<%= txtCity.ClientID %>').value;
```

Comment: +1 for beating me to it and mentioning the potential need to use `ClientID` ;)

Answer (score 5):

Providing you have `id` attributes on the textboxs you could easily have a one-liner in jQuery doing the following:

`$("#txtShipCity").text($("#txtCity").text());` (or `$("#txtShipCity").val($("#txtCity").val());` if you are dealing with an `input`)

If jQuery isn't really an option then try

```
document.getElementById("txtShipCity").value = document.getElementById("txtCity").value
```

Comment: I answered a minute before you but you get up-voted instead. Nice, SO users. ;) Correct answer though, so I might as well give you a +1.